# Line up the rows in table with list

Tags: tables, lists, line

I have this code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{4.70cm}}
\toprule
Gesture & NDO  & NSO & TNO & TNP &  Characteristics \\
\hline
    Goal   & 1 & 1 & 2 &1& \tabitem Randomly distributed of static object.\\
    Two Points    & 1& 2 & 3 & 1 & \tabitem Randomly distributed of static.\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip\centering
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

1. This what I got. My question is: How can line up the rows? the first item in the last column is not aligned with the row.

[image: table]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that contains the documentclass and relevant packages (How is `\tabitem` defined?)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is it to be inserted  in a two-column document?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,float, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\tabitem{\textbullet\enspace}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[H]
\centering\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}l|cccc >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\toprule
Gesture & NDO & NSO & TNO & TNP & Characteristics \\
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
    Goal & 1 & 1 & 2 &1& \tabitem Randomly distributed of static object.\\[1.5ex]
    Two Points & 1& 2 & 3 & 1 & \tabitem Randomly distributed of static.\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with use of the package `enumitem` and defining special type of column type for lists:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{I}{ >{\compress\itemize}X<{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\enditemize}}
\newcommand*{\mcbf}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}c}{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setlist[itemize]{wide}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l cccc >{\RaggedRight}I @{}}
    \toprule
Gesture & NDO   & NSO   & TNO   & TNP   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Characteristics} \\
    \midrule
Goal    & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & \item Randomly distributed of static object. \\
Two Points
        & 1     & 2     & 3     & 1     & \item Randomly distributed of static.\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]